# Clickable Buttons using libGDX

Tags: java, netbeans, libgdx

I have made my first game in java using LibGDX and netBeans. Its very simple so there are probably a lot of things I can improve. I want to implement a character selection screen, however I dont know how to make clickable images. Im going to post my entire code because im not sure what is relevant.

```
    package com.stars.game;

    import java.util.Iterator;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton;

    public class Stars extends ApplicationAdapter {

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    long starFly = 1;
        long horsePower = 0;
        long musicPlay = 0;
    long starCount = 0;
        long fakeFishCount = 0;
        long jellyLives = 3;
        long horseLives = 3;
    int shouldJump = 0;
    int horseShouldJump = 0;
    int win = 0;
        int start = 1;
    private Texture starImage;
        private Texture shellImage;
        private Texture blueStarImage;
    private Texture jellyImage;
        private Texture seaHImage;
    private Texture fishImage;
    private Texture loseImage;
        private Texture shockImage;
        int fishRate = 2000000000;
    private Sound dingSound;
    private Sound backround;
    private Sound wompSound;
    private Sound jumpSound;
        private Sound popSound;
        private Sound fishHitSound;
        private Sound shellSound;
        private Sound shootSound; 
    private Rectangle jellyfish;
        private Rectangle seahorse;
        private Rectangle mouseSquare;
    private Array<Rectangle> stars;
        private Array<Rectangle> shocks;
        private Array<Rectangle> shells;
        private Array<Rectangle> blueStars;
    private Array<Rectangle> fishs;
        private Array<Rectangle> fakeFishs;
    private long lastStarTime;
        private long lastShellTime;
        private long lastShockTime;
    private long lastFishTime;
        private long lastFakeFishTime;
        private long lastBlueStarTime;
    private long jumpTime;
        private long horseJumpTime;
        private long musicTime;
        private long musicTime2;
        float maxJumpHeight;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    Texture img;
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    BitmapFont font;

    @Override
    public void create () {

        font = new BitmapFont();

        starImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("star.png"));
                shellImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("seashell.png"));
                blueStarImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("blueStar.png"));
        dingSound = Gdx.audio.newSound((Gdx.files.internal("charlieDing.mp3")));
                shellSound = Gdx.audio.newSound((Gdx.files.internal("shellSound.mp3")));
                shootSound = Gdx.audio.newSound((Gdx.files.internal("zoop.mp3")));
        wompSound = Gdx.audio.newSound((Gdx.files.internal("womp.mp3")));
                popSound = Gdx.audio.newSound((Gdx.files.internal("pop.mp3")));
        jumpSound = Gdx.audio.newSound((Gdx.files.internal("sashaJump.mp3")));
                fishHitSound = Gdx.audio.newSound((Gdx.files.internal("fishHit.mp3")));
        backround = Gdx.audio.newSound((Gdx.files.internal("sashaBackround.mp3")));
        fishImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("fish.png"));
                shockImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("lightning.png"));
        jellyImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("jellyfish.png"));
                seaHImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("seahorse.png"));
        loseImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("youLose.png"));




        //Sets textures


        //Sets sounds

                musicTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        backround.play();
        //Makes music loop and makes it play at the start

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        //ortho = 2d
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800,480);

        //800 by 480 pixel camera, false/true whether camera points down
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        //draws the screen
        mouseSquare = new Rectangle();
                mouseSquare.x = Gdx.input.getX();
                mouseSquare.y = Gdx.input.getY();
                mouseSquare.width = 10;
                mouseSquare.height = 10;

        jellyfish = new Rectangle();
        jellyfish.x = 800 / 2 - 64 /2;
        //center screen half camera width, half of bucket rectangle width
        jellyfish.y = 63;
        //height off the ground
        jellyfish.width = 60;
        jellyfish.height = 100;


                seahorse = new Rectangle();
        seahorse.x = 800 / 2 - 64 /2;
        //center screen half camera width, half of bucket rectangle width
        seahorse.y = 63;
        //height off the ground
        seahorse.width = 60;
        seahorse.height = 110;
        //dimensions of bucket rectangle
        starFly = 1;

        stars = new Array<Rectangle>();
                shells = new Array<Rectangle>();
                blueStars = new Array<Rectangle>();
        fishs = new Array<Rectangle>();
                shocks = new Array<Rectangle>();
                fakeFishs = new Array<Rectangle>();
        //creates array value  for array of raindrops
        spawnStar();
                spawnBlueStar();
        spawnFish();
                spawnShell();

        //calls spawnRainadrop function below
    }

    private void spawnShell(){
        if(starFly == 1){
        Rectangle shell = new Rectangle();
        //creates raindrop
        shell.y = MathUtils.random(80, 480 - 50);
        //makes random x location between 800 and 64
        shell.x = -8500;
        //sets height off the ground
        //dimensions
        shell.width = 50;
        shell.height = 50;
        shells.add(shell);



        //adds the raindrop to the array
        lastShellTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
                if(jellyLives == 0 && horseLives == 0){
                    shell.y = MathUtils.random(80, 480 - 50);
        //makes random x location between 800 and 64
        shell.x = -8500;
                }
        }
        //records the amount of time since last raindrop
    }


         private void spawnShock(){
        if(starFly ==  1 && TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastShockTime > 2100000000 ){
        Rectangle shock = new Rectangle();
        //creates raindrop
        shock.y = jellyfish.y + 30;
        //makes random x location between 800 and 64
        shock.x = jellyfish.x;
        //sets height off the ground
        //dimensions
                shootSound.play();
        shock.width = 50;
        shock.height = 70;
        shocks.add(shock);

        lastShockTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

        //adds the raindrop to the array

        }
        //records the amount of time since last raindrop
    }
        private void spawnStar(){
        if(starFly == 1){
        Rectangle star = new Rectangle();
        //creates raindrop
        star.y = MathUtils.random(80, 480 - 50);
        //makes random x location between 800 and 64
        star.x = -50;
        //sets height off the ground
        //dimensions
        star.width = 50;
        star.height = 50;
        stars.add★;



        //adds the raindrop to the array
        lastStarTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        }
        //records the amount of time since last raindrop
    }

        private void spawnBlueStar(){
        if(starFly == 1 && starCount >= 50){
        Rectangle blueStar = new Rectangle();
        //creates raindrop
        blueStar.y = MathUtils.random(80, 480 - 50);
        //makes random x location between 800 and 64
        blueStar.x = -50;
        //sets height off the ground
        //dimensions
        blueStar.width = 50;
        blueStar.height = 50;
        blueStars.add(blueStar);



        //adds the raindrop to the array
        lastBlueStarTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        }
        //records the amount of time since last raindrop
    }
    private void spawnFish(){
        if(starFly == 1){
        Rectangle fish = new Rectangle();
        //creates raindrop
        fish.y = MathUtils.random(80, 480 - 50);
        //makes random x location between 800 and 64
        fish.x = 800; 

        //sets height off the ground
        //dimensions
        fish.width = 50;
        fish.height = 50;
        fishs.add<"(((<3enter code here;



        //adds the raindrop to the array
        lastFishTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        }
    }

       /* private void spawnFakeFish(){
            if(fakeFishCount < 1){
        Rectangle fakeFish = new Rectangle();
        //creates raindrop
        fakeFish.y = MathUtils.random(80, 480 - 50);
        //makes random x location between 800 and 64
        fakeFish.x = 800;
        //sets height off the ground
        //dimensions
        fakeFish.width = 50;
        fakeFish.height = 50;
        fakeFishs.add(fakeFish);



        //adds the raindrop to the array
        lastFakeFishTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        }
        }
*/
        //records the amount of time since last raindrop
    private void reset(){

        if(jellyLives == 0 && horseLives == 0){
        win = 0;
        fishRate = 2000000000;
        starCount = 0;
        starFly = 1;
        jellyLives = 3;
        horseLives = 3;
        jellyfish.y = 63;
        seahorse.y = 63;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0.2f,1);
        //backround color RGB from 0-1 transparency at end
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        //clears entire screen

        camera.update();
        //refreshes camera with new render


        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        //tells spritebatch to render in the coordinate system
        //specified by camera

        batch.begin();


                if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - musicTime > 1870000000 && musicPlay == 0 && jellyLives > 0 ||TimeUtils.nanoTime() - musicTime > 1870000000 && musicPlay == 0 && horseLives > 0){
                    musicPlay = 1;
                    musicTime2 = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
                }
                if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - musicTime2 > 1870000000 && musicPlay == 1 && jellyLives > 0 || TimeUtils.nanoTime() - musicTime2 > 1870000000 && musicPlay == 1 && horseLives > 0){
                         backround.play();
                         musicPlay = 0;

                         musicTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
                }
                if(start == 1){
                    batch.draw(seaHImage, Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
                }
        if(win == 1){
            batch.draw(loseImage, 0 - 25 , 0);
            font.draw(batch, "Click to try again", 380 - 25, 180 - 20);
            font.draw(batch, "Score: " + starCount, 380 - 25, 180 - 40);
        }
        batch.draw(jellyImage, jellyfish.x , jellyfish.y);
                batch.draw(seaHImage, seahorse.x - 20 , seahorse.y);
        if(win == 0){
        font.draw(batch, "Stars Caught: " + starCount, 30, 30);
                font.draw(batch, "Jellyfish Lives: " + jellyLives, 800 - 170, 30);
                font.draw(batch, "Seahorse Lives: " + horseLives, 800 - 170, 50);
        }
        for(Rectangle star: stars) {
            batch.draw(starImage, star.x , star.y);

        }
                for(Rectangle shock: shocks) {
            batch.draw(shockImage, shock.x , shock.y + 10);

        }
                for(Rectangle shell: shells) {
            batch.draw(shellImage, shell.x , shell.y);

        }
        for(Rectangle blueStar: blueStars) {
            batch.draw(blueStarImage, blueStar.x , blueStar.y);

        }
        for(Rectangle fish: fishs) {
            batch.draw(fishImage, fish.x , fish.y);

        }
                for(Rectangle fakeFish: fakeFishs) {
            batch.draw(fishImage, fakeFish.x , fakeFish.y);

        }
        batch.end();
                /*
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.E)){
                    spawnStar();
                }
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)){
                    horseLives = 0;
                }
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.Z)){
                    if(jellyLives == 0){
                        jellyfish.y = 63;
                    }
                    jellyLives++;
                }
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.X)){
                    if(horseLives == 0){
                        seahorse.y = 63;
                    }
                    horseLives++;
                }
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.Q)){
                    spawnFish();
                }
                */
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) jellyfish.x -= 600 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) seahorse.x -= 1200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) jellyfish.x += 600 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.R)) {
                    jellyLives = 0;
                    horseLives = 0;
                    reset();
                }
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE)) {
                    spawnShock();

                }
                if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) seahorse.x += 1200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
                 if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN) && seahorse.y > 63) {
                     horseShouldJump = 0;
                     horsePower = 1;
                 }
                 if(seahorse.y > 63 && horsePower == 1){
                     seahorse.y -= 1200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

                 }
                 if(seahorse.y <= 63){
                     horsePower = 0;
                 }
        //if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) player.y += 600 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
               // if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) player.y -= 600 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
                if((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W) && shouldJump == 0 && jellyfish.y < 800) ) {
                    jumpTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
                jumpSound.play();
                    shouldJump = 1;

                }
                if((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP) && horseShouldJump == 0 && seahorse.y < 800)){
                    horseJumpTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
                jumpSound.play();
                    horseShouldJump = 1;
                }
                if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
                    reset();
                    } 

                if(jellyfish.x < 0) {
                    jellyfish.x = 0;
                }
                //stops player from moving off screen left
                if(jellyfish.x > 800 - 80) {
                   jellyfish.x = 800 - 80;
                }

                        if(seahorse.x < 0) {
                    seahorse.x = 0;
                }
                //stops player from moving off screen left
                if(seahorse.x > 800 - 60) {
                   seahorse.x = 800 - 60;
                }

        if(shouldJump == 1){

            jellyfish.y += 12 - (jellyfish.y/30);

        }
        if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - jumpTime > 1860000000 && shouldJump == 1|| TimeUtils.nanoTime() - jumpTime > 1860000000 && shouldJump == 2 ){
            maxJumpHeight = jellyfish.y;
            jellyfish.y -= 12 - (jellyfish.y/30);
            shouldJump = 2;
        }
        if(jellyfish.y <= 63 && shouldJump == 2){
            jumpTime = 0;
            shouldJump = 0;
            maxJumpHeight = 0;
        }

                if(horseShouldJump == 1){

            seahorse.y += 12 - (seahorse.y/30);

        }
        if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - horseJumpTime > 1860000000 && horseShouldJump == 1|| TimeUtils.nanoTime() - horseJumpTime > 1860000000 && horseShouldJump == 2 ){
            maxJumpHeight = jellyfish.y;
            seahorse.y -= 12 - (seahorse.y/30);
            horseShouldJump = 2;
        }
        if(seahorse.y <= 63 && horseShouldJump == 2){
            horseJumpTime = 0;
            horseShouldJump = 0;
            maxJumpHeight = 0;
        }

        if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastStarTime > 1000000000/2) spawnStar();
        //calls spawnRaindrop function if more than 1000000000 nanoseconds have gone by

        Iterator<Rectangle> iter = stars.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle star = iter.next();
            star.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(star.x > 800) iter.remove();
            if(star.overlaps(jellyfish) || star.overlaps(seahorse)) {
                starCount++;
                dingSound.play();
                iter.remove();
            }
            //plays sound and removes raindrop if it gets the bucket or hits the bottom of the screen

        }


        //calls spawnRaindrop function if more than 1000000000 nanoseconds have gone by
        //hi

        Iterator<Rectangle> iter6 = shells.iterator();
        while(iter6.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle shell = iter6.next();
            shell.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(shell.x > 800){
                            shell.x = -8500;
                            shell.y = MathUtils.random(80, 480 - 50);
                        }
            if(shell.overlaps(jellyfish)) {
                            if(horseLives > 0){
                jellyLives++;
                            }
                            if(horseLives == 0){
                                horseLives++;
                                seahorse.y = 63;
                            }
                shellSound.play();
                                shell.y = MathUtils.random(80, 480 - 50);
                shell.x = -8500;
            }
                        if(shell.overlaps(seahorse)) {
                            if(jellyLives > 0){
                horseLives++;
                            }
                            if(jellyLives == 0){
                                jellyLives++;
                                jellyfish.y = 63;
                            }
                shellSound.play();
                                shell.y = MathUtils.random(80, 480 - 50);
                shell.x = -8500;
            }
            //plays sound and removes raindrop if it gets the bucket or hits the bottom of the screen

        }

                if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastBlueStarTime > 2147483000/2) spawnBlueStar();
        //calls spawnRaindrop function if more than 1000000000 nanoseconds have gone by

        Iterator<Rectangle> iter3 = blueStars.iterator();
        while(iter3.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle blueStar = iter3.next();
            blueStar.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(blueStar.x > 800) iter3.remove();
            if(blueStar.overlaps(jellyfish) || blueStar.overlaps(seahorse)) {
                starCount += 3;
                dingSound.play();
                iter3.remove();
            }
            //plays sound and removes raindrop if it gets the bucket or hits the bottom of the screen

        }



                if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastFakeFishTime > 1){
                    if(fakeFishCount < 2000){
                   /* spawnFakeFish(); */
                    }
                }
        //calls spawnRaindrop function if more than 1000000000 nanoseconds have gone by

        Iterator<Rectangle> iter5 = fakeFishs.iterator();
        while(iter5.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle fakeFish = iter5.next();
            fakeFish.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(fakeFish.x < -80){
                            fakeFishCount++;
                            iter5.remove();
                        }
            /*if(fish.overlaps(jellyfish)) {
                jellyfish.y = 9000000;
                starFly = 0;
                win = 1;
                wompSound.play();
                iter5.remove();

            }*/
            //plays sound and removes raindrop if it gets the bucket or hits the bottom of the screen

        }

                if(starCount > 50){
                    fishRate = 1300000000;
                }
                if (jellyLives == 0){
                    jellyfish.y = 9000000;
                }

                if (horseLives == 0){
                    seahorse.y = 9000000;
                }

                if(horseLives == 0 && jellyLives == 0){
                    win = 1;
                    starFly = 0;
                    backround.pause();
                            dingSound.pause();
                            popSound.pause();

                }
        if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastFishTime > fishRate) {
                    spawnFish();
        //calls spawnRaindrop function if more than 1000000000 nanoseconds have gone by
                    }
        Iterator<Rectangle> iter2 = fishs.iterator();
        while(iter2.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle fish = iter2.next();
            fish.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(fish.x < -800) iter2.remove();
            if(fish.overlaps(jellyfish)) {
                            jellyLives--;
                            popSound.play();
                            if(jellyLives == 0){

                            wompSound.play();
                            }
                            iter2.remove();
                        }
                            if(fish.overlaps(seahorse)){
                                horseLives--;
                                popSound.play();
                                if(horseLives == 0){
                              wompSound.play();


                                }
                                iter2.remove();
                            }

            Iterator<Rectangle> iter7 = shocks.iterator();

        while(iter7.hasNext()) {

            Rectangle shock = iter7.next();
                        shock.y += 4;
            if(shock.y > 520) iter7.remove();
            if(fish.overlaps(shock)) {
                                fishHitSound.play();
                iter7.remove();
                                iter2.remove();
            }

            //plays sound and removes raindrop if it gets the bucket or hits the bottom of the screen

        }   
            }
            //plays sound and removes raindrop if it gets the bucket or hits the bottom of the screen

        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui package classes. Example below:

```
public class ScreenMainMenu implements Screen{
private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;

public ScreenMainMenu(StartScreen startScreen){
}

@Override
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), false);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/skins/skin.json"));

    buildMenu();
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    stage = null;
    skin = null;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0.2f,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}

private void buildMenu(){
    Table menuTable = new Table(skin);
    menuTable.setPosition(0, 0);
    menuTable.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    menuTable.align(Align.top);

    stage.addActor(menuTable);

    Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/ubuntulogo.png"));
    Image image = new Image(texture);

    //first option
    image.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            //your action on click
        }
    });
    menuTable.add(image);

    //second option
    ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(image.getDrawable());
    imageButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            //your action on click
        }
    });
    menuTable.add(imageButton);

    //third option
    Button button = new Button(skin);
    button.add(image);
    button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            //your action on click
        }
    });
    menuTable.add(button);

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

There might be some small differences depending on version of libgdx, especially Stage constructor may be different.

Comment: Thank you for answering, the problem is i dont understand what most of that is doing. Do you think you could point me somewhere to a rutorial or something similar that would help me learn more?

Comment: There you can find most of the things explained: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui There is nice videotutorial playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLXY8okVWvwZ0JOwHiH1TntAdq-UDPnC2L